# Something like .hiverc for Hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, cloudera, hue

I would like to be able to configure hue/hive to have a few custom jar files added and a few UDFs created so that the user does not have to do this every time.

Ideally, I am hopeful that there might be a feature similar to the Hive CLI's "`.hiverc`" file where I can simply put a few HQL statements to do all of this. Does anyone know if Hue has this feature? It looks like it is not using the file `$HIVE_HOME/conf/.hiverc`.

Alternatively, if I could handle both the custom jar file and the UDFs separately, that would be fine too. For example, I'm thinking I could put the jar in `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` on all of the tasktrackers, and maybe also on Hue's classpath somehow. Not sure, but I don't think this would be too difficult...

But that still leaves the UDFs. It seems like I might be able to modify the Hive source (`org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry` probably) and compile a custom version of Hive, but I'd really rather not go down that rabbit hole if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this jira: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1066 [beeswax] Preload jars into the environment.